# Parsing double with dot to comma

Tags: c#, parsing, internationalization, double, cultureinfo

I am working with doubles. In the Netherlands we make use of 51,3 instead of 51.3. I did write a piece of code that works with dots instead of commas. But the result of the previously written code returns a double the English way, with a dot. I am encountering some strange errors.

Here is what I have:

```
var calResult = 15.2d;
var calResultString = calResult.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
var result = double.Parse(calResultString);
```

1. calResult == "15.2" -> as expected
2. calResultString == "15,2" -> as expected
3. result == "152" -> here I expect a comma.

A also did try to add the cultureinfo also in the double.Parse. This resulted in a "15.2".

TLDR: I need to convert an English/American double to a Dutch(or similar rules) one.

Thanks in advance! :)

P.S

I hope this is not a duplicate question, but didn't found anything this specific.

Comment: I don't understand the question. A `double` has no concept of culture, there's no such thing as an "English/American double". When you turn a `double` into a string, *then* the culture becomes important, because that determines e.g. what character is used for the decimal place. If you're looking at your `double` in a debugger, remember that the debugger is turning it into a string for you, using some culture.

Comment: `var result = source.Parse(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));` having a `string` which is a floating point in `en-US` we turn it into a `string` which represents the same floating point but in `nl-NL`

Comment: What happens if you do `var result = double.Parse(calResultString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));` ?

Comment: @Matthew "*A also did try to add the cultureinfo also in the double.Parse. This resulted in a "15.2".*"

Comment: @DmitryBychenko If `calResultString` is `"15,2"`, then parsing it with the US culture will result in a double with a value of `152`.

Comment: @canton7 Yes, but *which* CultureInfo? If he used the US culture (or the InvariantCulture) then the result would be wrong.

Comment: @MatthewWatson CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL")

Comment: @canton7 Why do double parsers have the option for a culture then?

Comment: @JeroenJonkman Then you're not giving us the whole story, because `double.Parse("15,2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));` will *definitely* return `15.2`.

Comment: @Jeroen If you're parsing a string which uses e.g. ',' as the decimal separator, `double.Parse` needs to know this, so it can correctly interpret it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You, probably, should either provide `"nl-NL"` whenever you work with Netherlands' culture

```
  var calResult = 15.2d;
  var calResultString = calResult.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
  // We should parse with "nl-NL", not with CurrentCulture which seems to be "en-US"
  var result = double.Parse(calResultString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```

Or specify `CurrentCulture` (default culture)

```
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL");

  var calResult = 15.2d;
  // now CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL") is redundant 
  var calResultString = calResult.ToString(); 
  var result = double.Parse(calResultString);
```

Finally, if you have a `string` which represents some *floating point value* in `en-US` culture, and you want the *same value* but be a `string` in `nl-NL` format:

```
  string source = "123.456";

  string result = double
    .Parse(source, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
    .ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the illusion that there were different kind of doubles, there are not. But your explanation makes it very (+ comments under question) clear!

Answer (score 1):

Numbers and strings don't contain any culture information, instead you specify the culture when you convert between numbers and strings.

> result == "152" -> here I expect a comma

What happened is that you asked the operating system to parse "15,2" into a double, and didn't specify a culture. It defaulted to US culture and ignored the comma.

If you'd specified a culture:

```
var result = double.Parse(calResultString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```

it would have given you the right value (15.2), and that might even have been displayed as 15,2 if your computer was configured to the right number format (and the debugger used your preference).

Ideally you don't hard-code the culture, but use the culture that the user has chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a simple method that will check for the coma character in your input and replace it with a dot. I believe the best way is to take an input as a `string` value. this way you can manipulate it and then you can parse it and return a double or a string if you wish:

```
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    double parsedDouble;
    if (input.Contains(","))
    {
        input = input.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
    }
    if (!Double.TryParse(input, out parsedDouble))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error parsing input");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(parsedDouble);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

edit: the answers from Robin Bennett/Dmitry Bychenko are much better than mine, as mine is just more manual. I wasn't aware of the overload of `parse` that he had provided.
I'll leave my solution, cause it does solve this issue, even if it's a bit more... brute ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var calResult = 15.2d;
 var calResultString = calResult.ToString();

string result = double.Parse(calResultString).ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```